# Show that if $\int_A f$ exists and $B$ has volume, then $\int_B f$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, riemann-sum

Let f be a real-valued function on a subset $A$ on $E^n$ and let $B \subset A$. Show that if $\int_A f$ exists and $B$ has volume, then $\int_B f$ exists.

**Note:** *Volume* is the *Jordan measure*. Integration is Riemann type.

**Edit:** I deleted my work for the first part as I assumed it was correct. I just need help with the above.

Will this work?

$$\int_A f = \int_{E^n} f \Bbb 1_A
$$
$\Bbb 1_B$ exists because $B$ has volume ($\Bbb 1$ is indicator function). Thus,
$$\int_{E^n} f \Bbb 1_B
$$
exists.  And,
$$\int_{E^n} f \Bbb 1_B = \int_B f
$$

This seems too easy.

Comment: what does $E^n$ mean?

Comment: Metric space of $n$ dimensions. You can switch it out for $\Bbb R^n$ if you desire.

Comment: Do we know anything of topological nature about $A$ and $B$? In particular, are they compact? You also don't tell almost anything about $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch of proof:

Let assume that the set A is bounded, so it can enclosed in a rectangle. Now, we know that function $g:A \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann-integrable iff set of discontinuities of $g$ forms a set of measure zero (i.e.  for all $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a disjoint finite rectangle cover whose jordan measure is less than $\epsilon$).

We know that $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann-integrable, so its' set of discontinuities has zero measure. Furthermore, set $B \subset A$ has a volume. Which means that $1_B$ is Riemann-integrable and thus its' set of discontinuities has also zero measure.

To show that $\int_B f$ exists it is enough to show that discontinuities of function $1_B \cdot f$ has zero measure.

The main idea is to enclose discontinuities of both function separately with families of disjoint rectangles, $C_1, C_2$ with jordan measures of $m(C_1),m(C_2) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then forming  a new family $C_3 = C_1 \cup C_2$. Functions $f$ and $1_B$ are continuous outside of set $C_3$, thus, their product is also continuous. Now,  Measure of the set $C_3$ is at most $m(C_1) + m(C_2) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$. Thus, discontinuities of $1_B \cdot f$ form a set of zero measure.

---

This is just a sketch of proof. To be more precise we need to be more careful about:

- assumptions on the set A (is it bounded, rectangle or does it have a volume itself)
- form of Lebesgue criterion that we use (is the measure Jordan or Lebesgue and what we assume from the set that we integrate over)